# Distribute a fixed range of dates within the same ID

Tags: excel, data-comparison

I have a table that lists hotel reservations by ID, each with a check in and check out dates. I can sort this by ID, but I need to distribute (on a separate column) each day of the stay (Starting with the check in date and excluding the check out date).

I  hope the file in the link below explains what I mean (The intended result column is listed as "Target")

https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0dt285lnntne7k/CHALLENGE.xlsx

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What have you tried ?  You can use formulas to add to dates eg `=A1+1` gives you the next day after the date in A1.

Comment: I have tried using COUNTIF and COUNTIFS in order to differentiate a range within the same reservation ID but haven't succeeded yet.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're trying to acheive.  It would help to update your workbook to show exactly what the "after" layout looks like.

Comment: Hi Tim, the workbook has a "Target" column, the Answer proposed by pnuts worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(A1=A2,D1+1,B2)
```

in D2 and copied down to suit.

Comment: Worked as intended, thank you so much for the solution, simple, elegant and accurate!!!